# Disable ringtone for incoming SMS from bank

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, ringtone, contact-groups

I have a Sony Z1 Compact with Android 4.4. I have a subscription to get text messages whenever my credit card is charged. Some of these payments are handled at night, probably because the payment is handled overseas. I disable 4G at night, but keep the phone connection on at night, so I hear incoming SMS messages.

I know I can create groups, add contacts to those groups, and then disable ringtones for this group. This service has no number, and cannot be added to the contacts, and thus not added to a group.

**How can I disable the ringtone for just this service?**